# Tasks are open in Windows 8 Taskbar but they cannot be opened

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, taskbar

I'm trying to fix a major issue in Windows 8.  I'm finding that some programs have tasks open (in preview miniature mode) in the Taskbar for the same program, but when you click on them, Windows 8 does nothing.  On my last reboot, this happened with TextPad.  Now I can't open TextPad or Google Chrome.  This is now becoming a serious issue and Windows is now unusable.  How can I fix this?

Note, I have dual monitors set up.  Not sure if this would matter?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, I had to click on screen "1" in the screen resolution settings, and disable that display.  Apparently, the windows were hiding in the 3rd monitor.  Notice how it turned black.  I have no clue why I can't make my main screen "1" and leave screen "3" out of the mix.

[image]